# Fixing broken package dependencies on debian, broken pipe error

Tags: linux, debian, apt, texlive

My texlive package got broken, I've tried to reinstall it but when I run apt --fix-broken install broken pipe error comes out. I've done apt-get autoclean, apt-get autoremove, apt-get clean and it's does not fix the issue. What should I do?

```
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/0-texlive-base_2020.20200417-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/generic/iftex/iftex.pdf', which is also in package texlive-generic-extra 2016.20170123-5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of texlive-base, which would be broken by installation of texlive-plain-generic ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure texlive-base (broken by texlive-plain-generic)
Preparing to unpack .../1-texlive-plain-generic_2020.20200417-1_all.deb ...
De-configuring texlive-base (2016.20170123-5) ...
Unpacking texlive-plain-generic (2020.20200417-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/1-texlive-plain-generic_2020.20200417-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/bibtex/abstyles/README.gz', which is also in package texlive-generic-extra 2016.20170123-5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../2-fonts-adf-accanthis_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-adf-accanthis (0.20190904-1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/2-fonts-adf-accanthis_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/adf/AccanthisADFStd-Bold.otf', which is also in package ttf-adf-accanthis 0.20090423-2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../3-fonts-adf-gillius_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-adf-gillius (0.20190904-1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/3-fonts-adf-gillius_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/adf/GilliusADF-Bold.otf', which is also in package ttf-adf-gillius 0.20090423-2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../4-fonts-adf-universalis_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-adf-universalis (0.20190904-1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/4-fonts-adf-universalis_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/adf/UniversalisADFStd-Bold.otf', which is also in package ttf-adf-universalis 0.20090423-2
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of texlive-base, which would be broken by installation of texlive-latex-extra ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure texlive-base (broken by texlive-latex-extra)
Preparing to unpack .../5-texlive-latex-extra_2020.20200417-1_all.deb ...
De-configuring texlive-base (2016.20170123-5) ...
Unpacking texlive-latex-extra (2020.20200417-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/5-texlive-latex-extra_2020.20200417-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/classpack/classpack.sty', which is also in package texlive-htmlxml 2016.20170123-5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of texlive-base, which would be broken by installation of texlive-formats-extra ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure texlive-base (broken by texlive-formats-extra)
Preparing to unpack .../6-texlive-formats-extra_2020.20200417-1_all.deb ...
De-configuring texlive-base (2016.20170123-5) ...
Unpacking texlive-formats-extra (2020.20200417-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/6-texlive-formats-extra_2020.20200417-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/aleph/base/News', which is also in package texlive-omega 2016.20170123-5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of texlive-base, which would be broken by installation of texlive-lang-other ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure texlive-base (broken by texlive-lang-other)
Preparing to unpack .../7-texlive-lang-other_2020.20200417-1_all.deb ...
De-configuring texlive-base (2016.20170123-5) ...
Unpacking texlive-lang-other (2020.20200417-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/7-texlive-lang-other_2020.20200417-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/fonts/bengali/README', which is also in package texlive-lang-indic 2016.20170123-5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of texlive-base, which would be broken by installation of texlive-latex-extra-doc ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure texlive-base (broken by texlive-latex-extra-doc)
Preparing to unpack .../8-texlive-latex-extra-doc_2020.20200417-1_all.deb ...
De-configuring texlive-base (2016.20170123-5) ...
Unpacking texlive-latex-extra-doc (2020.20200417-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/8-texlive-latex-extra-doc_2020.20200417-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/support/classpack/MANIFEST', which is also in package texlive-htmlxml 2016.20170123-5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/0-texlive-base_2020.20200417-1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/1-texlive-plain-generic_2020.20200417-1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/2-fonts-adf-accanthis_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/3-fonts-adf-gillius_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/4-fonts-adf-universalis_0.20190904-1.1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/5-texlive-latex-extra_2020.20200417-1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/6-texlive-formats-extra_2020.20200417-1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/7-texlive-lang-other_2020.20200417-1_all.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/8-texlive-latex-extra-doc_2020.20200417-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Which GNU/Linux distribution and which version you're running?

Answer (score 0):

The output shows that you are trying to install a new set of **texlive** packages with partly new package names. The new packages contain files which are part of the old packages as well, hence `dpkg` errors out before breaking installed packages.

#### Approach 1

`dpkg`/`dpkg-deb` is good in resolving package dependencies automatically, you can try to use `apt` for that:

```
apt install /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/[0-8]-*1_all.deb
```

*NB: When using the above command, take care that the glob only matches the desired packages.*

#### Approach 2

If `apt` as well fails to resolve the dependencies automatically, i.e. removal of conflicting old **texlive** packages, I would simply remove the old ones manually first. Create some backup first, but "removing" deb packages usually leaves data and config files in place:

```
apt remove texlive-generic-extra ttf-adf-accanthis ttf-adf-gillius ttf-adf-universalis texlive-htmlxml texlive-omega texlive-lang-indic
apt install /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-Awvjbo/[0-8]-*1_all.deb
```

#### Approach 3

In theory it is possible to manipulate the packages file lists, so that `dpkg` does not recognise the conflicts anymore. That would allow to install the new packages without removing the old ones. But most likely those practically conflict anyway or the old ones will be obsolete at best. However just for completeness, the file lists are usually located in:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package_name>.list
```

For example:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/texlive-generic-extra.list
```